# Subscript or Superscript text within a Zend Form label

Tags: html, zend-framework, label, zend-form

I would like to include subscript text in a Zend_Form_Element's label, and it doesn't seem to be working:

```
 $zend_form_element->setLabel('Label <sub>x</sub>');
```

Is there anything I can do to get it to output properly without having to manually write the form on the view page? Thanks for the help,

Dave

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the right way to do it:

```
$zend_form_element->addDecorator('Label', аrray('escape'=>false));
```

from: http://forums.zend.com/viewtopic.php?f=69&t=5706

Answer (score 6):

I would say that best way is to get actual decorator from element and then set escape option, not to add new decorator:

```
$zend_form_element->getDecorator('Label')->setOption('escape',false);
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. None of the answers work for me.
The text I set the label for is always escaped.
This is what my element code looks like: http://pastebin.com/tRV9Rx0p

Comment: Ah, found out. $this->setElementDecorators() was called later and was overwriting all my changes.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$zend_form_element->setAttribs( array( 'escape' => false ) )
                  ->setLabel( 'Label <sub>x</sub>' );
```

Or the singular:

```
$zend_form_element->setAttrib( 'escape', false )
                  ->setLabel( 'Label <sub>x</sub>' );
```

Comment: That was close, but apparently, you have to put 'escape' => false on the actual decorator for the form element:

    $zend_form_element->addDecorator('Label', аrray('escape'=>false));

Answer (score 1):

You can also it it the following way:

```
$radioElement = new Zend_Form_Element_Checkbox('formelement_0');
$radioElement->setLabel('Do you accept the <a href="#">Terms &amp; Conditions</a>?');
$radioElement->getDecorator('Label')->setOption('escape', false);
```

Answer (score 0):

From @fireeyedboy's answer, you can also do the following directly in your Zend_Form:

```
$this->addElement(
'radio',
'name',
array(
    /* more settings */
    'attribs'   => array(
        'escape' => FALSE
    )
));
```