# Equivalent of URL helper inside Zend Form

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I have a zend form, and I need to provide a dynamic link on the form. ie. user tries to select from drop-down -> if desired option not present, click on the adjacent link to open another form where they can add the option. The link will be dynamic because I want to post some data from the current form using GET (the country and region already selected for example).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this client-side using javascript/AJAX - detect clicking on the link, collect form data and continue to a different page. If you need a fancy URL of the other page, you'd have to make an AJAX call to the server to get the fancy URL based on the form parameters,

or

make the link a submit button actually, process the form server-side (detecting that the special submit button was clicked; example [here](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/handling-multiple-submits-in-a-single-form-with-php/5242116)) and do a redirect to your other page.

As for rendering the link next to a Zend_Form_Element, you can do this in a few ways, one of them would be placing it in the label or description (`setLabel()`, `setDescription()`) while making sure to set the `escape` parameter of the decorator to `false` (example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2473629/subscript-or-superscript-text-within-a-zend-form-label))

Answer (score 2):

```php
Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter()->assemble($urlOptions, $name, $reset, $encode)
```

IE:

```
Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter()->assemble(array('controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'index'), null, true)
```

Same as in the Zend_View_Helper_Url...